# Make child process not zombie until waitpid

Tags: linux, unix, process, waitpid

Is there Linux or POSIX method for instructing a process to not turn into a zombie when it finishes and the parent does not call `waitpid()`?

I know that the parent process we could use `SA_NOCLDSTOP` for the `SIGCHLD` handler but that is not an option in my case because the parent is busy and `SIGCHLD` is in use for other things.

Is there a way to mark a specific child process to just quietly die by itself, if I am not interested in the exit code?

Answer (score 1):

You will always need to wait for a child process, however if you follow this procedure, then you can wait for a child that will die quickly, and let init inherit your 'real' process. Init will then tidy up for you.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void main(void) {
    int ret;
    pid_t child1;
    pid_t child2;
    int status;

    child1 = fork();
    if (child1 == -1) {
        /* error */
        exit(1);
    }

    if (child1 == 0) {
        /* in the child... we create a new session, and then re-fork */
        setsid();

        child2 = fork();
        if (child2 == -1) {
            exit(1);
        }

        if (child2 == 0) {
            /* call execve() or a friend */
            ret = execlp("sleep", "sleep", "6", NULL);

            /* we should _never_ get here - unless the execlp() fails */
            fprintf(stderr, "execlp() returned: %d\n", ret);
            exit(1);
            for(;;);
        }

        sleep(2); 

        /* success ... child1 dies here */
        exit(0);
    }

    sleep(4);

    ret = waitpid(child1, &status, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        /* unfortunately we can only determine the state of our 'proxy' process...
         * to get any further information / the child-child PID, then you'll need to use a pipe to share the information */
        fprintf(stderr, "waitpid() returned %d\n", ret);
    }

    sleep(4); 

    return;
}
```

The various sleep durations should allow you to see the following events (watch `top` or something).

## Step 1

All processes start, all linked as children of your shell

- 17336 - My shell
- 21855 - The application
- 21856 - Child1 (the proxy process)
- 21857 - Child2 (the useful child process)

`top` output:

```
attie    17336 17335  0 16:04 pts/36   00:00:00 -bash
attie    21855 17336  0 16:34 pts/36   00:00:00 ./test
attie    21856 21855  0 16:34 ?        00:00:00 ./test
attie    21857 21856  0 16:34 ?        00:00:00 sleep 6
```

## Step 2

**Child1** dies, and becomes a zombie / defunct, **Child2** gets inherited by init (PID 1)

```
attie    17336 17335  0 16:04 pts/36   00:00:00 -bash
attie    21855 17336  0 16:34 pts/36   00:00:00 ./test
attie    21856 21855  0 16:34 ?        00:00:00 [test] <defunct>
attie    21857     1  0 16:34 ?        00:00:00 sleep 6
```

## Step 3

**Child1** gets cleared up by the parent in the call to `waidpid()`

```
attie    17336 17335  0 16:04 pts/36   00:00:00 -bash
attie    21855 17336  0 16:34 pts/36   00:00:00 ./test
attie    21857     1  0 16:34 ?        00:00:00 sleep 6
```

## Step 4

**Child2** dies, and gets cleared up by init

```
attie    17336 17335  0 16:04 pts/36   00:00:00 -bash
attie    21855 17336  0 16:34 pts/36   00:00:00 ./test
```